# browser action set badge action for firefox addon

Tags: notifications, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, browser-action

I need to show notification on firefox addon using sdk. Its very much similar to chrome's browser action set badge text.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Adnan Bashir

Comment: What code do you have so far? If show it to us we can hook up the badge for you

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: thanks although I have solved the problem but any alternative will be greatly appreciated